# How do I join two paths in Figma?

Tags: vector, figma

I'm trying to draw a symmetrical shape in Figma. Usually the way I do this is by drawing a path, then duplicating it and flipping it horizontally. In Illustrator, I would then be able to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the two paths, creating a closed shape that I could then fill.

But in Figma, when I select two paths, the Vector -> Join Selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) menu option is disabled. How do I join these vectors together?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can make both lines part of the same vector by using **Flatten** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).

Then you can select the points in the vector that you want to connect together and join them using **Vector** → **Join Selection** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>), or by using the Pen tool.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Are there pre-conditions? e.g. paths must cross ...etc?

Comment: Not that I know of. Try opening a new Figma document, draw two lines (crossing or not), select both, right-click -> Flatten. If the two lines become one object named "Vector", it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I got to do it this way and it worked smoothly:

Step 1: **Outline the strokes** (<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>)

Step 2: **Union selection**

Step 3: **Flatten** (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>)

[You can View the Demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy3jr4g3bc9d54q/2021-01-20%2011.52.07.gif?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: none of the answers made sense until I saw the video.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad the video made sense @conman253  I made it using Gifox (an awesome app) because that’s how I report bugs  to our engineering team. I’m a “show, don’t tell” kind of guy.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by selecting two paths and then directly flattening the selection, without any boolean operation before.
If one end point from one path is overlapping another one from the second path then, when flattening, the points seems to become one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use the pen and then join manually by clicking on each point. This created a straight joint line between the two points I wanted to connect (which was quite frustrating to iron out) but I managed to at least create a fillable vector by joining the lines.